# I'd like all files created in a specific directory to automatically get 755 permissions, is that possible?

Tags: centos6, chmod

The relevant folder is over-written every couple of days but I want it's content to retain the 755 permissions.
I've tried `chmod g+s dir` but to no avail.
Is that even possible?

Comment: check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory

Comment: What do you mean to no avail? What happens ?

Comment: The next time the folder is over-written the files there get 655 instead of 755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the posix permissions model; there is simply no provision for it.  A related provision (setuid and setgid on directories) allows ownership to be inherited to one level, but not permissions.

You should consider using ACLs if you need this functionality, as those *can* be made to be inherited (at file creation time anyway), but this requires a bit of thought to your permissions structure.  Assuming you have POSIX ACL support on your system and in your filesystem, the ACL you want to set on the directory is going to be something like `d:u::7,d:g::5,d:o::5` (this makes the ACL operate on the UID and GID the file is owned by; if you need to inherit that too make the directory suid and sgid).  Default ACLs on directories are applied to new files and directories created within them, so while this isn't exactly a way of making the permissions on the files 0755, it will probably do what you need.

There is a bit of a learning curve to ACLs and they are one of the more complex (and very rarely used) features in POSIX.  Read the manpages: `man 5 acl` and `man 1 setfacl`.  Do not attempt to use ACLs for anything until you understand how they work.

The other thing to look at, depending on how the contents of the directory are being written, is having the program that is writing them specify the permissions; this would be subject to umask, but is the only way to effect the desired permissions in the literal way you want to do it.  Many programs have options you can specify for this, or you can set the umask you want in the shell running the program creating the files (you can do this without affecting the system umask).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I've already ran this: `setfacl -Rm g:users:rwX,d:g:users:rwX folder/` and it didn't do the trick for me so I'd like to fallback but I'm not sure about the syntax, can you please assist me?

Comment: If you want to remove all the ACLs from the hierarchy I believe you can use `setfacl -Rbk folder`.  To remove just the ACLs from your command it should be `setfacl -Rx g:users,d:g:users folder`.  To revert to what they were before, if they weren't empty, the usual way is to use the `--restore` option and a backup from `getfacl -R`.  That said, the ACL you have there would grant the `users` group +rw -x by default, and not affect the user or others permissions at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess i'll just change the rsync command not to override permissions

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with additional software, and arn't needing subfolders, you could trigger off a command to change permissions (for example chmod 755) when files are added to the folder with [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en). You'll need to install incron, add yourself to the allowed user list (by adding yourself to /etc/incron.allow )

You would then set up a incrontab entry with `incrontab -e`, then adding a line like `/path/to/directory_to_monitor IN_MODIFY chmod 755` to it. If you want to go deeper into the options incron has, check out the manpage, or [this guide on howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/triggering-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron).

Its probably not very elegant (since it watches for file changes), but set up correctly, should change the permissions of files automatically to what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure the inotify mechanism upon which that relies supports recursion through subdirectories.

Comment: he didn't mention recursion in his question, and I explicitly ruled out inotify for that specific scenario.

Comment: True.  I'm not saying you're wrong, just commenting, perhaps slightly redundantly.